# Is there a term for "all-or-nothing" in terms of ideals?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, linguistics

So I've got the following:

"You're either with us, or against us," so you're XXX or XXX-minded

"You have black-and-white thinking," so "You have XXX thinking"

and "The people who support a philosophy such as this one, have a mindset of all-or-nothing."

Please illuminate me, I just feel like there's an encompassing term.

Comment: "Orthodox" implies strict adherence to some doctrine.

Answer (score 3):

***absolutist***

> [ODO definition of ***absolutist***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/absolutist)
>
> ab·so·lut·ist
>
> - noun
>
> 1.
>   a person who holds absolute principles in political, philosophical, or theological matters.
>
> "*he was a moral absolutist with little patience for shades of gray*"
>
> - adjective
>
> 1.
>   relating to or supporting absolute principles.
>
> "*an absolutist political tradition*"

Comment: Just FYI, most definitions on Google Dictionary, these days, come from Oxford Dictionaries. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/absolutist

Comment: cool. NVZ  I'll use that then

Comment: but there's no need to go back and edit all your previous answers. Let it be. :)

Comment: Great term. +1.

Answer (score 0):

The 'ideal' is a fallacy called [false dilemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_dilemma) or false dichotomy.

> A false dilemma (also called false dichotomy, false binary, black-and-white thinking, bifurcation, denying a conjunct, the either–or fallacy, fallacy of exhaustive hypotheses, fallacy of the excluded middle, the fallacy of false choice, or the fallacy of the false alternative[citation needed]) is a type of informal fallacy in which something is falsely claimed to be an either-or situation, when in fact there is at least one additional option.

(Wikipedia)

---

In psychology, the term is [splitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_(psychology)):

> Splitting (also called black-and-white thinking or all-or-nothing thinking) is the failure in a person's thinking to bring together the dichotomy of both positive and negative qualities of the self and others into a cohesive, realistic whole. It is a common defense mechanism used by many people.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_dilemma) The individual tends to think in extremes (i.e., an individual's actions and motivations are all good or all bad with no middle ground).